# DropdownList returning int value instead of text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have two DDLs

**Create View**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stage, "Stage", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
  <div class="col-md-offset-0">
    @Html.DropDownList("Stage", String.Empty) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Stage)
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InternalApprovalAuthorities, "Internal Approval Authority", new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
  <div class="col-md-offset-1">
    @Html.DropDownList("InternalApprovalAuthorities", string.Empty) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InternalApprovalAuthorities)
  </div>
</div>
```

In my edit view I only want to see the information they display.

**Edit View**

```cs
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stage, "Stage", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
       @ViewBag.StageText
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Stage)
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InternalApprovalAuthorities, "Internal Approval Authority", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5"})
    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
        @*@Html.Display("InternalApprovalAuthorities")*@
        @ViewBag.InternalApprovalAuthoritiesText
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InternalApprovalAuthorities)
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller** -

This code resides in my Get Create

```html
ViewBag.InternalApprovalAuthorities = new SelectList(db.InternalApprovalAuthorities, "InternalApprovalAuthoritiesID", "InternalApprovalAuthoritiesText");
```

This code resides in both my Get and Post for my User edit view

```cs
Stage stage = db.Stages.Where(t => t.StageID == imsregister.Stage).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.StageText = stage.StageText;

InternalApprovalAuthority internalapprovalauthorities = db.InternalApprovalAuthorities.Where(a => a.InternalApprovalAuthoritiesID == imsregister.InternalApprovalAuthorities).FirstOrDefault();
if(internalapprovalauthorities != null)
{
    ViewBag.InternalApprovalAuthority = internalapprovalauthorities.InternalApprovalAuthoritiesText;
}
```

Both are constructed in the same manner. However Stage returns the text value I need. InternalApprovalAuthorities doesn't return anything if I use `@ViewBag.InternalApprovalAuthorities`, and if I use `Display("InternalApprovalAuthorities")` it returns the int value instead of text.

Any Ideas on what this issue is?

Comment: What dropdownlist are you referring to? All you have shown is hidden inputs

Comment: The InternalApprovalAuthorities dropdownlist. I have several dropdownlists in my application and all display correctly and I know that this displays an Int value because using Display shows this, but I can't get it to return the actual text that I need. The text is linked to this dropdownlist in my database table

Comment: You have not shown any code relating to a dropdownlist

Comment: Sorry Stephen, I should clarified, this is a user edit view, in my create view it is a dropdownlist but in the user edit view they can only see the text value of what they previously selected in the create view.

Comment: Your question related to dropdownlist's. You need to show the code relating to them. Impossible to even understand what the issue is until you show the relevant code.

Comment: I've updated my post Stephen, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Still confused - your `ViewBag` property is named `InternalApprovalAuthorityvb` yet in the view you refer to `InternalApprovalAuthorities` (in the `@DisplayFor()`) and `@ViewBag.InternalApprovalAuthoritiesText` - all are different names. And your controller code suggests property `InternalApprovalAuthorities` is a complex object so this will not bind on post back anyway (you cannot bind a hidden input to a complex object). And why are you using `ViewBag` anyway?

Comment: Again apologizes Stephen I was testing using "vb" I need to remove that in my post and code. I used viewbag because it returned the text to view, just like it did with Stage. I thought it would simply be a matter of doing the same again with InternalApprovalAuthorities

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91736/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-scanner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had a conflict because my class was called InternalApprovalAuthority and my ViewBag had the same name. To solve this all I did was rename the ViewBag in the View and Controller, thus giving me the text value I wanted.

**Edit View**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InternalApprovalAuthorities, "Internal Approval Authority", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5"})
  <div class="col-md-offset-0">
    @ViewBag.IAA @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InternalApprovalAuthorities)
  </div>
</div>​
```

**Controller GET and POST**

```
       InternalApprovalAuthority internalapprovalauthorities = db.InternalApprovalAuthorities.Where(a => a.InternalApprovalAuthoritiesID == imsregister.InternalApprovalAuthorities).FirstOrDefault(); 
       if (internalapprovalauthorities != null) 
        { 
           ViewBag.IAA = internalapprovalauthorities.InternalApprovalAuthoritiesText;
        }
```